# Server send an raw image in axios, how to convert it to base64 or other way to use this image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, base64, httpwebresponse

From the following link, I get an image. Unfortunately, it shows the image in the preview tab of inspect element of the network. but in res.data it shows broken text. How will I be able to use this image in img tag like . I also shared what it returns to me in console and preview

```
export const getProfilePhoto = async (userType) => {
    return await axios.get(`${API_URL}/staff/profile-photo`,{ headers : authHeader(userType) })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
}
```

This is what it shows in console

[image]

this is what it shows in preview

[image]

highly expecting some suggestions and solution

I'm sorry for any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you find a way to access this image without needing the extra headers, so you can just let the browser handle it directly:

```
<img src="{API_URL}/staff/profile-photo" />
```

If you can't do that, then you will need to get a blob and create an object URL.

```
fetch(
  `${API_URL}/staff/profile-photo`,
  {
    headers: authHeader(userType)
  }
).then(res => res.blob()).then((blob) => {
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```